# How to get SMS log in android

Tags: android

I am exporting logs using csv file in android.I am getting only call logs but not getting sms logs.Here is the code

```
    while (curLog.moveToNext()) {
                String callName = curLog
                        .getString(curLog
                                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                if (callName == null)
                    callName="Unknown";

                String callNumber = curLog.getString(curLog
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));


                String callDate = curLog.getString(curLog
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));



                String callType = curLog.getString(curLog
                        .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));


                    String duration = curLog.getString(curLog
                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                 data.add(new String[] {callName,callNumber,callDate,callType,duration});

            }
```

Please suggest how to fix it.....

Comment: check this two answer: [one][1] and [two][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15638148/1168654
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15761291/1168654

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar i am not reading sms i have to just get the log

Comment: I have the same issue on both of my samsung devices. Researching this issue indicates it is problem with how samsung handles the android logs, it merges them. Obviously this is incorrect and inconsistent behavior. Note, an sms message cannot be deleted through the call log api, yet it can be retrieved through the call log api. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13161461/1168654  for more detail check this link they get call & sms count using two diffrent method:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621893/how-to-get-missed-call-sms-count

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

This is my way of getting the SMS. It can get body, content, date of the current message as well as check if it is incoming or outgoing. In addition, it can get the contact name that matches the phone number by another method.

> First of all, add permission to AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.app.myapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
... 
  </manifest>
```

> Secondly, implement SMS Observer class to get the information you need

```
public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver {       
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "SMSObserver";
    private static final Uri SMS_URI = Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI;    //get uri depending on different devices

    public SMSObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    //this onChange method will be fired up when you send or receive message
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_URI, null, null, null, Telephony.Sms.DATE + " DESC");
        String phNumber = null;
        //make sure there is a message being operating
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            try {
                //the meanings of those variables are quite straight forward
                String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.TYPE));    
                String content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.BODY));
                String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.DATE));
                Date SMSDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));
                phNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS));   //this is phone number rather than address

                String contact = getContactDisplayNameByNumber(phNumber);    //call the metod that convert phone number to contact name in your contacts

                int typeCode = Integer.parseInt(type);
                String direction = "";
                //get the right direction
                switch (typeCode) {
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX:
                        direction = "INCOMING";                            
                        break;

                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX:
                        direction = "OUTGOING";                           
                        break;

                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT:
                        direction = "SENT";                            
                        break;

                    default:
                        direction = "UNKNOWN";
                        Log.e(TAG, typeCode + " is unknown");
                        break;
                }

            } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SMSHelper: outgoingSMS", e);
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "\nName: " + contact + "\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nContent:--- "
                + content + " \nCall Date:--- " + SMSDate
                + " Direction: " + direction, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.i(TAG, "\nName: " + contact + "\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nContent:--- "
            + content + " \nCall Date:--- " + SMSDate
            + " Direction: " + direction + "\n----------------------------------");

        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }            


    /**
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712112/search-contact-by-phone-number
     * Look up phone number
     *
     * @param number  phone number
     * @return the name matched with the phone number
     */
    private String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
        String name = "<Not in contact list>";

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
                contactLookup.moveToFirst();
                name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                //String contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                Log.i(TAG, "Found number in contacts: " + number + " = " + name);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cursor is null or empty " + number + " not found in contacts");
            }
        } finally {
            if (contactLookup != null) {
                contactLookup.close();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

> If the device is on running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and the
>   app's target SdkVersion is 23 or higher, the SMS permission will be
>   considered as dangerous permission. Therefore you must get the right
>   permission beforehand .

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    &&ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //grant permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                        10);            
                return;
            }
```

> Lastly, instantiate the SMSObserver class in the HomeActivity class or any 
>   other Activity classes.

```
//sms log
        smsObserver = new SMSObserver(new Handler(), getApplicationContext());
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, true, smsObserver);
```